# Foreach loop displaying values in a certain format

Tags: php

I have two foreach loops in which are fetching results from mysql database table. The values are displaying correctly but I am trying to compress the results so it doesn’t repeat values. For example there are two `courses` and two `instructors` in the table. That means when I run the loop I expect for a total of 4 results to display. But after running through the loop a total of 8 results are shown. But the extra results are a repetition. It possible to loop through completely one foreach loop before going to the next? Or what is the best way so it displays exactly the 4 results?

```
$db_select  = $db_con->prepare("
SELECT      a.academy_id,
           ca.course_name,
           ca.course_start_date,
           ca.course_end_date,
           p.first_name,
           p.last_name
    FROM academy a
    INNER JOIN courses_by_academy ca ON a.academy_id = ca.academy_id
    INNER JOIN person p ON a.academy_id = p.academy_id
    WHERE a.academy_id = 123
");
if (!$db_select) return false;
    if (!$db_select->execute(array('123' => $acad_id))) return false;
    $results = $db_select->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (empty($results)) return false;
    $final_result = '';
    $final_result2 = '';

    foreach ($results as $value){
          $final_result .= "-------------------COURSES_OFFERED------------------</br>";
          $final_result .= "<b>Course Name: </b>".$value['course_name']."</br><b>Start Date: </b>".$value['course_start_date']."</br><b>End Date: </b>".$value['course_end_date']."</br>";      
    }

    foreach ($results as $value2){
          $final_result2 .= "---------------------STAFF-----------------------</br>";
          $final_result2 .= "<b>First Name: </b>".$value2['first_name']."</br><b>Last Name: </b>".$value2['last_name']."</br>";
    }

}
```

Current Echo Display of results:

```
-------------------COURSES_OFFERED------------------
Course Name: Biology
Start Date: 2013-11-15
End Date: 2013-11-27
-------------------COURSES_OFFERED------------------
Course Name: Biology
Start Date: 2013-11-15
End Date: 2013-11-27
-------------------COURSES_OFFERED------------------
Course Name: Calculus
Start Date: 2013-11-16
End Date: 2013-11-30
-------------------COURSES_OFFERED------------------
Course Name: Calculus
Start Date: 2013-11-16
End Date: 2013-11-30
--------------------STAFF-----------------------
First Name: Person1
Last Name: Last1
---------------------STAFF-----------------------
First Name: Person2
Last Name: Last2
---------------------STAFF-----------------------
First Name: Person2
Last Name: Last2
---------------------STAFF-----------------------
First Name: Person1
Last Name: Last1
```

Seeking for a results like this:

```
-------------------COURSES_OFFERED------------------
Course Name: Biology
Start Date: 2013-11-15
End Date: 2013-11-27
-------------------COURSES_OFFERED------------------
Course Name: Calculus
Start Date: 2013-11-16
End Date: 2013-11-30
--------------------STAFF-----------------------
First Name: Person1
Last Name: Last1
---------------------STAFF-----------------------
First Name: Person2
Last Name: Last2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your sql will result to 4 rows

```
p1 biology
p2 biology
p1 calculus
p2 Calculus
```

try using LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN

Comment: ok you can create two queries. 1 for staff and 1 for courses, instead of joing them together

Answer (score 0):

Since you are concatanating the string in each iterartion the value will be appeneded in the variable.So after each iteration the value in the variable is not getting cleared  bu it is appending.So intitializing the variable in the loop itself will solve your probelm.

```
foreach ($results as $value){
          $final_result = '';
          $final_result .= "-------------------COURSES_OFFERED------------------</br>";
          $final_result .= "<b>Course Name: </b>".$value['course_name']."</br><b>Start Date: </b>".$value['course_start_date']."</br><b>End Date: </b>".$value['course_end_date']."</br>";      
    }

    foreach ($results as $value2){
          $final_result2 = '';
          $final_result2 .= "---------------------STAFF-----------------------</br>";
          $final_result2 .= "<b>First Name: </b>".$value2['first_name']."</br><b>Last Name: </b>".$value2['last_name']."</br>";
    }
```

Comment: It only shows the one course and one staff not the whole result. It is supposed to show two courses and two staff